# jQuery: ajax POST with html entities

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, post, html-entities

I've been sending forms with jQuery ajax & $(this).serialize to php & database and it has worked perfectly. Now I have situation where I can't use serialized form but generate a string from different input fields instead and the problem is that it appears to lose some URL entities in the process.

for example "&phone=+358123456789" turns out "&phone= 358123456789" losing the plus character and ends up with whitespace to the database. "&phone=%2B358123456789" works fine though.

as there might be lots of other chars than "+" that could be lost, so I'm asking if there's a function similar to php's *htmlentities* that would convert a string? I've tried javascript's escape() & unescape() without success and meddled with jquery's .text() & .html() but that ended poorly aswell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) in your data string.

Answer (score 2):

You can still pass the data as an object to your [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (or [AJAX shorthand](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/)) methods, for example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'myPage.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { phone: $("#phone").val(),
          other: $("#other").val() }
});
```

You just pass the `{ param: value, param2: value }` object where you would have put [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) before.  [This method will call](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L511) [`encodeURIComponent()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) internally since that's what [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) that it uses does :)